# How do I find the screen location of all desktop shortcuts?

Tags: delphi, shortcut-file

We have a number of shortcuts that are placed on our customer desktops and like to keep them together for easy use, and away from other shortcuts that they may use for other programs.  If they change the screen resolution, monitor or make other changes to the display, the shortcuts become "scrambled".

I found some code examples to find other properties of shortcuts, eg. target, but I didn't see any properties that indicate where the shortcut is physically located on the screen.

I was thinking of creating a simple program that reads the location of our shortcuts and saves this to a file when they are in the correct locations.  A simple button press would allow them to be restored to their correct places.

I am programming in Delphi, we are using W7-10 on various customer machines.

Comment: I would personally despise any application that forcefully re-arranges where I choose to place my shortcuts.

Comment: There are 3rd party tools that save+restore Desktop icon positions after screen resolution changes. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Jerry Remote Desktop does exactly that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, and it also annoys the hell out of me, but it's such a standard tool, I have to bite my tongue and deal with it.

Comment: @Jerry What should it do? I have more screen space on the machine than on my laptop. What alternative does remote desktop have?

Comment: The main reason we need to do this is that the top left corner of the desktop is reproduced on a scoreboard visible to the public, so we want to be able to ensure that none of the shortcuts are located in this area.  Our shortcuts also get moved around by users and we would like to be able to restore ours to a particular area with a single double click.

Answer (score 3):

The shell API provides functionality for this. The key interface is [`IFolderView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775606.aspx), and in particular the methods [`IFolderView::GetItemPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775600.aspx) and [`IFolderView::SelectAndPositionItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775614.aspx).

Using the shell API is somewhat involved. As always, it takes to fair amount of scaffolding before you get to call these methods. I refer you to Raymond Chen's article, [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/18/10403054.aspx), which gives example code to do this.

Comment: The shell API may provide more structured access to the desktop items, but it still does not provide a direct link between a file/shortcut and its desktop icon, so you still have to enumerate the desktop items manually, comparing their display names to the intended files/shortcuts. At least Raymond's example shows how to do the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop is implemented as a standard Win32 [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx) control in icon mode.  The items on the Desktop are ListView items.  You can use the [`GetDesktopWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504.aspx) function to get the `HWND` of the Desktop's ListView and then use standard ListView messages to manipulate it as needed.

There is no API to retreive the Desktop ListView items that represent specific files/shortcuts, so you will have to look for them manually.  Either by:

1. looping through the items using [`LVM_GETITEMCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761044.aspx) and [`LVM_GETITEMTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761055.aspx), comparing each item's text to your shortcut names.
2. using [`LVM_FINDITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774903.aspx) to search for the item with the same text as a given shortcut name.

Once you have found the intended items, you can then use [`LVM_GETITEMPOSITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761048.aspx) and [`LVM_SETITEMPOSITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761192.aspx)/[`LVM_SETITEMPOSITION32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761194.aspx) to get/set the item positions as needed.

---

**UPDATE:**

Now, with that said... the fact that the Desktop uses a ListView for its icons is an *implementation detail* that you should not rely on, as it would eventually break:

[A reminder about the correct way of accessing and manipulating the position of icons on the desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211122-00/?p=105948)

> Starting in Windows 10 version 1809, **there were changes to the way that the positions of the desktop icons are managed**, and one of the consequences is that if you try to manipulate the icon positions by talking directly to the ListView control, those changes aren’t taken into account by the icon management code

The recommended approach is to use [`IFolderView::GetItemPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getitemposition) instead:

[Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933)

> Okay, we already have enough to be able to enumerate all the desktop icons and print their names **and locations**.
>
> ...
>
> After getting the IFolderView, ... We ask the view for its Items enumeration, then proceed to enumerate each of the items. For each item, ... , **and we ask the IFolder­View for its position**. Then we print the results.

Comment: This is a hack that relies on implementation details, details that are subject to change. Indeed the shell is now built on DirectUIHWND windows. Instead of hacking, one should use the shell API.

Comment: This works on Win7 but not Win10. I believe MS changed the desktop architecture in Win10. I believe you have to use the "IFolderView" approach mentioned in a previous answer. It's MUCH more complicated though.

Comment: Apparently, this no longer works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71974682/4788546.

Comment: @CristiFati I recently posted about that in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77979060/65863. I have added the information to this answer.