# ListView_GetItemPosition doesn't write to referenced pointer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the position of icons on the desktop (will ultimately be trying to move them). `ListView_GetItemCount()` returns the number of desktop icons successfully, so I know I have the correct window handle.

However, `ListView_GetItemPosition()`  doesn't write to `iconPos`.

```
int numberOfIcons = ListView_GetItemCount(folderView);
POINT iconPos = {};

ListView_GetItemPosition(folderView, iconIndex, &iconPos);

printf("Number Of Icons On Desktop is: %i\n", numberOfIcons);
printf("Icon by Index, Position = %ld, %ld", iconPos.x, iconPos.y);
```

I get no error msgs, but if I initialize `iconPos` with a set value, it remains the same, indicating `ListView_GetItemPosition()` isn't writing to `iconPos`.

[ListView_GetItemPosition Function Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_getitemposition)

Comment: Can you change it around a little so looks more like POINT iconPos = {}; ListView_GetItemPosition(folderView, iconIndex, &iconPos);

Comment: Sure thing, I'm pretty new to ++ & it'd be great to know, is this change just for readability or is there more to it?

Comment: You should be using the shell api rather than this sort of hacking.

Comment: For me, getting the desktop icon information through ListView_GetItemCount or ListView_GetItemPosition does not work. It cannot ensure that the desktop icon is in the Listview. You can use [IFolderView::GetItemPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getitemposition?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desktop ListView you are accessing exists in a different process than your app. The `POINT` object you give to `ListView_GetItemPosition()` must be allocated in the address space of the same process that owns the ListView.

You can use `VirtualAllocEx()` for that allocation, then request the position using that memory, then use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read the `POINT` data from that memory into a `POINT` allocated in your own process.

Try something like this:

```cpp
int numberOfIcons = ListView_GetItemCount(folderView);
printf("Number Of Icons On Desktop is: %d\n", numberOfIcons);

if (numberOfIcons > 0)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(folderView, &pid);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (!hProcess)
    {
        printf("OpenProcess failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        LPPOINT pt = (LPPOINT) VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(POINT), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
        if (!pt)
        {
            printf("VirtualAllocEx failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            POINT iconPos;
            SIZE_T numRead;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIcons; ++i)
            {
                if (!ListView_GetItemPosition(folderView, i, pt))
                {
                    printf("GetItemPosition failed for index %d\n", i);
                    continue;
                }

                if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pt, &iconPos, sizeof(POINT), &numRead))
                {
                    printf("ReadProcessMemory failed for index %d, error %u\n", i, GetLastError());
                    continue;
                }

                printf("Icon at Index %d, Position = %ld, %ld", i, iconPos.x, iconPos.y);
            }

            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pt, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I recall reading somthing about memory allocation akin to what you posted but this explination makes much more sense, much appreciated - G

Comment: There is no guarantee that the desktop icons are in a listview control. [Use IFolderView::GetItemPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791827/how-do-i-find-the-screen-location-of-all-desktop-shortcuts).