# Query desktop icons with LVM_GETITEMRECT in C# only yields position, not bounds. How to do it?

Tags: c#, winapi

I query the desktop icons by `LVM_GETITEMRECT` and only get the position of the icon. But I would also need the bounds.

Docu is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-getitemrect

It is this part I am not able to implement:

> When the message is sent, the left member of this structure is used to
> specify the portion of the list-view item from which to retrieve the
> bounding rectangle. It must be set to one of the following values ....

Here the code which is working, but only gets the position x/y. The width/height values are always 0. Remark: Complete code "frees" the memory in `finally`.

```
genericPtr = VirtualAllocEx(
    processHandle,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rectangle)),
    // Rectangle ist the maximum
    // sizeof(uint), ??? SIZE HERE ???
    AllocationType.Commit,
    MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, genericPtr.ToInt32());
Rectangle[] vRectangle = new Rectangle[1];
int rectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rectangle));
ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, genericPtr, 
                        Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(vRectangle, 0),
                        rectSize, out vNumberOfBytes);
```

I understand I have to set the `LVIR_Message` value for `SendMessage`, but how would I do it?

```
private enum LVIR_Message : uint
{
    LVIR_BOUNDS = 0,
    LVIR_ICON = 1,
    LVIR_LABEL = 2,
    LVIR_SELECTBOUNDS = 3
}
```

---

Ref to related question: [How can I disable "Auto arrange icons" of the Desktop view in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77958389/356726)

Comment: You just need to set the `left` using something like `WriteProcessMemory`. Side note: you are leaking that pointer, you need to free it in a `finally` (this is one pitfall in marshalling stuff yourself).

Comment: So I need to write into the memory `genericPtr.ToInt32()` is pointing to? And I assume this before `SendMessage`, correct? And the left is what? I would assume since it refers to a rectangle 4x32bit either the upper or lower of those 16bytes.

PS: "Leaking" is clear, the above code is simplified. The complete code does exactly this in `finally`.

Comment: Yes (although never convert `IntPtr` to `int` because it might be 64-bit). You would need to copy a `Rectangle` from your memory to the other process.

Comment: https://github.com/mwinapi/mwinapi/blob/a1bac7377c3dc176f8163fd392711348eaf7a358/ManagedWinapi/Windows/SystemListView.cs#L331

Comment: You're doing it wrong: [A reminder about the correct way of accessing and manipulating the position of icons on the desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211122-00/?p=105948).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `Rectangle` is the wrong type to use.  You need the `RECT` struct instead.

And, you need to Pin the rectangle with `GCHandle` before you can take its address.

And, you need to write the contents of the `Rectangle` into the target process before you then send the message.

And, you can't use `IntPtr.ToInt32()` if you compile your app for 64bit, you would need `IntPtr.ToInt64()` instead, as `LPARAM` changes size depending on the platform you are running on.

Try this instead:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

...

RECT[] vRectangle = new RECT[1];
vRectangle[0].left = LVIR_Message.LVIR_BOUNDS;

GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(vRectangle, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try 
{
    uint rectSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RECT));

    IntPtr rectPtr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    // or:
    // IntPtr rectPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(vRectangle, 0);

    IntPtr processAllocPtr = VirtualAllocEx(
        processHandle,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        rectSize,
        AllocationType.Commit,
        MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
    if (processAllocPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    try
    {
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(
            processHandle,
            processAllocPtr,
            rectPtr,
            rectSize,
            out vNumberOfBytesWritten))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr.ToInt64());
        }
        else
        {
            CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr.ToInt32());
        }

        // or, simply use/declare an overload of CWindow.SendMessage()
        // that takes an IntPtr instead of an int/int64....
        //
        // CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr);

        if (!ReadProcessMemory(
            processHandle,
            processAllocPtr,
            rectPtr,
            rectSize,
            out vNumberOfBytes))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(
          processHandle,
          processAllocPtr,
          0,
          MEM_RELEASE
        );
    }
}
finally
{
    gch.Free();
}

// use the updated vRectangle[0] as needed...
```

Alternatively:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

...

RECT vRectangle = new RECT();
vRectangle.left = LVIR_Message.LVIR_BOUNDS;

int rectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RECT));

IntPtr rectPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rectSize);
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(vRectangle, rectPtr, false);

    IntPtr processAllocPtr = VirtualAllocEx(
        processHandle,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        (uint)rectSize,
        AllocationType.Commit,
        MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
    if (processAllocPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    try
    {
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(
            processHandle,
            processAllocPtr,
            rectPtr,
            (uint)rectSize,
            out vNumberOfBytesWritten))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr.ToInt64());
        }
        else
        {
            CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr.ToInt32());
        }

        // or, simply use/declare an overload of CWindow.SendMessage()
        // that takes an IntPtr instead of an int/int64....
        //
        // CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_GETITEMRECT, itemId, processAllocPtr);

        if (!ReadProcessMemory(
            processHandle,
            processAllocPtr,
            rectPtr,
            (uint)rectSize,
            out vNumberOfBytes))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        Marshal.PtrToStructure(rectPtr, vRectangle);
    }
    finally
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(
          processHandle,
          processAllocPtr,
          0,
          MEM_RELEASE
        );
    }
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(rectPtr);
}

// use the updated vRectangle as needed...
```

---

Now, that being said, you are taking the completely wrong approach to begin with. The fact that the Desktop uses a ListView for its icons is an *implementation detail* that you should not rely on, as it would eventually break:

[A reminder about the correct way of accessing and manipulating the position of icons on the desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211122-00/?p=105948)

> Starting in Windows 10 version 1809, **there were changes to the way that the positions of the desktop icons are managed**, and one of the consequences is that if you try to manipulate the icon positions by talking directly to the ListView control, those changes aren’t taken into account by the icon management code

The *recommended* approach is to use [`IFolderView::GetItemPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getitemposition) instead:

[Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933)

> Okay, we already have enough to be able to enumerate all the desktop icons and print their names **and locations**.
>
> ...
>
> After getting the IFolderView, ... We ask the view for its Items enumeration, then proceed to enumerate each of the items. For each item, ... , **and we ask the IFolder­View for its position**. Then we print the results.

Unfortunately, that only gets you an icon's position, not its bounding rectangle.  I don't see a Shell API for retrieving that value.

Comment: Now I see what the docu meant by "left"

Comment: There's [`IFolderView::GetSpacing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getspacing) which represents, I guess, the extents of the bounding rectangle. I'm not sure how this is different from [`IFolderView::GetDefaultSpacing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getdefaultspacing).

Comment: @IInspectable that is not equivalent to `LVM_GETITEMRECT`, though.  `IFolderView::GetSpacing()` doesn't allow you to query individual items for their specific bounds. It assumes every item is the same size. But ListView items can have different sizes due to different text lengths, etc. Also, `GetSpacing()` includes whitespace between items, whereas `LVM_GETITEMRECT` does not.

Comment: After a while of searching I have found `sharpshell` which seems to provide an interface for C#.  I have also found a list of GUIDs including the Desktop and I will also check if this is an approach. Thanks for the hint.

The Raymond Chen article has been referred to several time, but I could not find a way to do it in C# yet (as in by other question).

https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/blob/main/SharpShell/SharpShell/Interop/IFolderView.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/known-folder-guids-for-file-dialog-custom-places?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Small fix, the struct RECT should be left, top, right bottom. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect

Comment: And for some reason I can only get it working with `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(rects, 0)` with `RECT[] rects = new RECT[1]; rects[0].left = (int)LVIR_Message.LVIR_BOUNDS;`, but then it seems to work. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: All values in `RECT`vRectangle` are always 0. With the array I get sound values. I understand `vRectangle` should contain the values after `ReadMemory` . When I look at it I only see all 0 values. Just by replacing `rectPtr` by `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(rects, 0)` as in my last comment  I see correct values.

Comment: @HorstWalter My bad, was not aware that `GCHandle.Alloc()` doesn't work with struct types (it makes a copy and then pins the copy). I have updated my example.

Comment: Affirm, works as well. Cheers!